# Copy values from datagridview to 2 dimension string C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, copy, tostring

I have a two-dimensional variable that looks like this :

```
  string[] Dimension = new string[]
        {
                        "+-----+", // -----> X     /\Y
                        "|XXXXX|",
                        "|XXXXX|",
                        "|XXXXX|",
                        "|XXXXX|",
                        "|XXXXX|",
                        "+-----+",
        };
```

Secondly i have the datagridview where is 6 rows + 6 columns.
Code for datagridview look like :

```
//Adding columns to datagridview
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("X0", "X0");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("X1", "X1");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("X2", "X2");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("X3", "X3");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("X4", "X4");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("X5", "X5");

//Adding rows to datagridview  
dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Y0");
dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Y1");
dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Y2");
dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Y3");
dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Y4");
dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Y5");

//Adding values to datagridview.    
dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value = "X";
dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[1].Value = "X";
dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[2].Value = "X";
dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[2].Value = "X";
dataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[3].Value = "X";
dataGridView1.Rows[4].Cells[3].Value = "X";
dataGridView1.Rows[4].Cells[4].Value = "X";
dataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[5].Value = "X";
```

After add this values it show in winforms like this :
[image]

How can i convert (copy) values from datagridview to my string named Dimension?

New string should exacly looks like this :

```
 string[] map = new string[]
        {
                        "+-----+", // -----> X     /\Y
                        "|XX   |",
                        "|XX   |",
                        "|  X X|",
                        "|  XX |",
                        "|     |",
                        "+-----+",
        };
```

Is is possible to to that? To get this "X" inside to have exacly this result?

Comment: Why does it need to follow this format? It looks similar to a markdown table, though your format is missing a column separator between cell values. You may be able to find a library that will convert from dgv to markdown, or write it yourself.

Comment: I need such a format to work properly in a later phase and exactly to pathfinding with algiritm A*

Comment: @MongZhu This assumes each "cell" or index contains exactly 1 char, how much data is stored there isn't clear in the example. Adam says above that it will contain some sort of file path, so given that we can assume that the value would be an indeterminate length.

Comment: @fourwhey granted. But then one needs only to accomodate for the length of the `Value` string. so the basic approach remains the same

Comment: @fourwhey "pathfinding" can also mean to find a path/way in a graph/field/matrix. Not necessarily related to files. Have a look at [Introduction to A*](http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/AStarComparison.html)

Comment: @MongZhu Ah you are correct.  I mistook his meaning. Thank you for the link.

Comment: So any idea how to do that ? :/

Comment: yes. each string in your array is internally represented as a `char[ ]` so you can loop through your datagridview and use the indices to access the corresponding positions in your map.

Comment: @Mong Zhu could you show a example how can i do that?

Comment: I wrote you an example of how this might be accomplished. Take a look

Comment: I will check it in few days thank you so much, and if works gonna accept answear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you would look through your datagrid view `Columns` and `Rows` using 2 for loops.

1) Create a new map:

```
string[] map = new string[dataGridView1.Rows.Count+1];
// give it a header
map[0] = "+" + new string('-', dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1) + "+";
```

using a [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netframework-4.7.2) you can costruct for each line/row a string that depends on the values in your grid.

```
for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("|"); // frame left border
    for (int j = 1; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        // try to get the value            
        string value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value?.ToString();
        // if there is no value => take a space otherwise take the value
        value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? " " : value;
        // plug it into your string builder
        sb.Append(value);
    }

    sb.Append("|");  // frame right border
    // lunge the finished string into the array
    map[i] = sb.ToString();
}
// close the frame
map[dataGridView1.Rows.Count] = "+" + new string('-', dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1) + "+";
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, map));
```

the resulting output in the console looks like this:

```
+-----+
|XX   |
|XX   |
|  X X|
|  XX |
|     |
|     |
+-----+
```